# vertically automatic scroll text of textview with specific time interval in android

Tags: android, timer, scroll, textview, scrollview

i am begginer in android. In my app i am having textview which has multiple lines of text , it may have 15-20 lines. i want vertical auto scroll of text within that textview. so what can be the solution?

here is my xml code :

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/Thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/imgres">
    <ScrollView      
        android:id="@+id/sv"     
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
        android:fillViewport="true" >

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    android:maxLines="10"
    />    
   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In function i have set the text of my textview using code below :

```
tv.setText(textArray);
```

Comment: have you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184054/android-auto-scrolling-text-in-textview

Comment: i have checked [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184054/android-auto-scrolling-text-in-textview) . but i want vertical scrolling. do you have any soution for that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a ScrollView actually.

Just set the

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER_NUMBER"

android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your TextView in your layout's xml file.

Then use:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

in your code.

Comment: Yes , this code works well. But I want to implement automatic scrolling with specific time interval.