# How to get Auto Scrolling text view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have text view in Footer and I Want to Scroll that text in Footer. Here is my snippet of my Code but that text will not be scrollable . Any body can help me 
Thanks in Advance
 My Code

```
public class Footer extends RelativeLayout{
    private TextView footer_TextVeiw;
    ImageView logout;
    public Footer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        String infService = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(infService);
        li.inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, this, true);
        footer_TextVeiw= (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text_Footer);  
        footer_TextVeiw.setSelected(true);    } }
```

**My XML Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Footer" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_Footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ECEFF5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
         android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:text="@string/Footer"
         />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184054/android-auto-scrolling-text-in-textview

Answer (score 1):

You can try attribute    `android:scrollbars="vertical" or Horizontal`

Comment: Hi i tried with this but i cant get.. Simply the text oly getting as a view not in Scrollable

Comment: When there is a overflow of text than only textView come with the scroll bar...try to provide fixed width for the TextView

Comment: Thanks Pragnani its perfectly works for when we give certain fixed width for text view

Comment: @ManojKumar welcome friend...you can accept this as answer if you think it helps you..

Answer (score 1):

set

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"

android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

in your TextView in xml file. and use

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```